# Convert multiple XML files (available as rows in database) into single Excel file all at a time

Tags: microsoft-excel, xml

I have multiple XML files which are available as records in database. I can export the records as CSV,XML,text file. I need to convert all the XML files into single Excel file.

OS : Windows 7

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT :**  I've installed power query add-in for EXCEL which might possibly  help me to do my task (as @mike suggested). The input would be something like this(XML file containing XML data as rows) :

[image]

Comment: Write a small XML parser program to convert the .XML files into a concatenated .CVS file.

Comment: Can you please help me out ? @Ramhound

Comment: help you write a program, I have the capability to write such a program, I just don't have the time to do so.

Comment: I've written a parser code that worked pretty fine @Ramhound. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  Power Query is a free Add-In from Microsoft for Excel 2010 and 2013, and is built into Excel 2016 on the Data ribbon, under Get & Transform.

The easiest way would be to export the CSV files to a folder.  Then click New Query / From File / From Folder.  Power Query will automatically detect column headings, data types etc and append the data from all the files in the folder into a single Excel Table.

No code is needed.

Comment: I've understood what you said and I got power query add-in to my Excel. But the thing is that I can export all XML(datatype) records from database to a single CSV/text/XML. And exporting all the XML records to single file and importing it into EXCEL is not working with power query add-in. Can you please help me out ? @Mike

Comment: Possibly, but I'll need more info than "is not working".

Comment: Please refer the edit in the question. And please let me know what should be the next step if I have input like that ?

Comment: That file doesnt look like standard XML to me. It looks like an initial line of text, then XML documents on each line?  Power Query can still handle that with a bit of fiddling. I would Import it as a text file, then edit the query. I would remove the first row, then use Transform / Text Columns / Parse / XML. This results in a table on each row.  You can expand the Tables manually or expand all using a PQ function e.g.  https://gist.github.com/Mike-Honey/f5f3f708310eb1de7f4a

Comment: What is the **Transform / Text Columns / Parse / XML** exactly means ? @Mike

Comment: From the Power Query "Query Editor" window, go to the Transform ribbon, then within the Text Column section click the Parse button and choose the XML option.

Answer (score 0):

Open the folder with the xml files, create new column merging **Folder Path** & **Name** ==> **Path**, remove the other columns, add new column with the code **Xml.Tables(File.Contents([Path]))**, keep expanding.
That's it.